# How and where do I assign the reference ID?

Tags: java, mongodb

I am new to web programming and I see a lot of articles and posts about creating a good API and creating a good web page.  But not too many articles go into the area of HOW the api and the web page interact with respect to setting / getting references in a 1 to many database model

I am starting with the following models:

User

```
const UserSchema = new Schema({
    email: {type: String, required: true},
    password: {type: String, required: true},
})
```

Address

```
const AddressSchema = new Schema({    
    street: {type: String, required: true},
    city: {type: String, required: true},
    state: {type: String, required: true},
    zip: {type: String, required: true},
})
```

I would like to use a reference and "populate" to link both of these models together. ( https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html ) as the user may have many addresses (work, home, billing, office, shipping etc )

I have a some questions

Should I hold the an array of references in User to an Address:

```
const UserSchema = new Schema({
email: {type: String, required: true},
password: {type: String, required: true},

address: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Address' }]

})
```

OR should I hold the reference in Address to the User

```
const AddressSchema = new Schema({    
    street: {type: String, required: true},
    city: {type: String, required: true},
    state: {type: String, required: true},
    zip: {type: String, required: true},

    user: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }

})
```

Next, I am also making the assumption that a good API follows the single responsibility principle (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) and when called, the API ***only creates the user (or) address*** and does nothing more.

By making that assumption, when / where and how do I assign the reference ID(s) in either User or Address?

Where and when do I call the "populate" method in order to fill the result set?

I need some best practice advise and/or a really good example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case the condition is 'One-to-Few' means one user will not have more than 10 address or in worst case lets consider 20. So embedding both of them in one document will work most effectively.

So I would advice you to keep both in one collection.

```
const UserSchema = new Schema({
email: {type: String, required: true},
password: {type: String, required: true},
address: [{
    street: {type: String, required: true},
    city: {type: String, required: true},
    state: {type: String, required: true},
    zip: {type: String, required: true}
}]

})
```

And if you want it in different collection then holding the reference in Address to the User is best because first thing you will have in db will be users collection then you will update address.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/7585179/jits : Thank you for the advice.  I am going to keep them in separate documents.  What about the when/where to call populate?

Comment: It depends on how you want your data for example this query

`User.
  find(...).
  populate('address').
  exec()`

this will yield result 

`[
     {
             email:"abc@gmail.com",
             password:"qwer",
             address:[
                   { 
                          street:"",
                          city:"",
                           state:"",
                           zip:""
                   }
             ]
     }
]`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/7585179/jits - Was this a good question?  did it outline all of the necessary information required for you to come up with an answer?  If so, can you please up vote it?  thanks